# Dual Boot Ubuntu & Mac

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, mac, uefi

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed. Just installed Mac OS X, updated GRUB, which generates 2 Mac entires (32bit & 64bit). But when I try booting from these, it just restarts. I suppose I need EFI GRUB? Which I tried installing. But I think, the EFI partition needs to be the first partition? I currently have it like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pNYO.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all... are you tring to run Mac Os on a non-apple hardware?
Anyway as far as I know yes, efi partition should be the first. I don't think you need to install grub efi since i can start mac os from bios grub (on a mac trough bios emulation). It seems to me it has crappy performances tough.
Easyest way to solve this is installing MacOS before Ubuntu, if you don't want that you should provide informations on your hardware, on your partition table and on you grub configuration.

Comment: Yes, I am actually on a self-built PC. Performance is so far ok. Havent tried games tho

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://technocreed.com/2011/10/27/triple-booting-mac-os-x-windows-7-and-linux-operating-systems/) might help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.